# Why won't this chatbox center?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container chat" style="width: 50%; margin: 0px auto;">
    <div class="chat-bar"><h1>Wolf Valley Chat</h1></div>
    <div class="chat-content">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <script id="cid0020000091912718480" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 800px;height: 350px;">{"handle":"wolfvalleychat","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"202020","b":91,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","f":91,"i":91,"k":"202020","l":"202020","m":"202020","n":"FFFFFF","o":91,"p":"10","q":"202020","r":91,"t":0,"surl":0,"allowpm":0,"cnrs":"0.35","fwtickm":1}}</script>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is the code for a chatango chatbox that I've placed on my website. For some reason, It centers, but the centering is off. What should I do to correct this?

Comment: you need to set the table's and iframe's width to 100%

Comment: Ok, I set the width to 100%, but no it's shifted completely to the left

Comment: div.container needs to stay as you have in the question, the table inside of div.chat-content needs to have the 100% width, as the iframe that's inside that table too

Comment: I tried adding the style="width: 109%;" in chat-content, but the table is still on the left of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `width` of the outmost div to `100%`, and make the `table` `margin: 0 auto`. Here is the final code:

```
<div class="container chat" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="chat-bar" style="text-align:center"><h1 style="color:white">Wolf Valley Chat</h1></div>
    <div class="chat-content">
        <table style="margin: 0 auto">
            <tbody>
                <script id="cid0020000091912718480" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 800px;height: 350px;">{"handle":"wolfvalleychat","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"202020","b":91,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","f":91,"i":91,"k":"202020","l":"202020","m":"202020","n":"FFFFFF","o":91,"p":"10","q":"202020","r":91,"t":0,"surl":0,"allowpm":0,"cnrs":"0.35","fwtickm":1}}</script>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked. It doesn't show on my iPad  but I checked it with my computer and it fit right in the center. There is a small gap right above it where the title is supposed to be, but it's not showing. What should I do for that?

Comment: It looks like the text color is set to black for the title, so it is blending in with the background (which is why you can't see it). I updated the code above to make the color white, and added `text-align: center` so the text is centered above the chatbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `margin:0 auto` for centering, **you must define** the div's width in order to center things. you can fix class `container chat`'s width. ex.

```
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto;" class="container chat">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's in your iframe's width, you have at 800px when it should be 100%

```
<div class="container chat" style="width: 50%; margin: 0px auto;">
<div class="chat-bar"><h1>Wolf Valley Chat</h1></div>
<div class="chat-content">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <script id="cid0020000091912718480" data-cfasync="false" 
async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" 
style="width: 100%;height: 350px;">
{"handle":"wolfvalleychat","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"202020","b":91,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","f":91,"i":91,"k":"202020","l":"202020","m":"202020","n":"FFFFFF","o":91,"p":"10","q":"202020","r":91,"t":0,"surl":0,"allowpm":0,"cnrs":"0.35","fwtickm":1}}</script>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```